# umbraco how to update multiple prevalue programatically

Tags: umbraco, member, multiple-choice, customproperty

I have a member type which has a custom property - lets name it **books** - of data type checkbox - so multiple choice is possible.

Now I'm trying to update this member programatically with new values for **books**. In the customxml it comes as cdata, I'm passing a value as

```
umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member member =  umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member.GetMemberFromEmail(email);
member.SetProperty("memberBooks", booksValue);
member.Save();
```

where 'booksValue' is a string of values seperated with comma - because it's how it appears in the contentXml.

It doesn't work.

The question is - how do I update the member property/ xml with new multiple values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what you need to do:

```
umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member member = umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member.GetMemberFromEmail(email);
member.getProperty(“memberBooks”).Value = booksValue;
member.Save();
```

I hope this should work. I haven't tried it since long-time but this is how I used it.

Comment: Hi @Ankur Ghelani, thank but I tried it and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this issue.

Both

```
member.getProperty(“memberBooks”).Value = booksValue;
```

and

```
member.SetProperty("memberBooks", booksValue);
```

work

I was just passing wrong values.

In the contentXml they display as values but actually I need to update the property with the ids so if the data type is checkbox list and the values are like:

1 - book

2 - booko

3 - booki

then in the contentXml it displays as a list "book,booko,booki" but to update it programatically I had to pass: "1,2,3" to the property.

So it should be:

```
member.SetProperty("memberBooks", "1,2,3");
```

instead of:

```
member.SetProperty("memberBooks", "book,booko,booki");
```

I hope it helps others with the same problem.

Comment: I am glad that you have found solution

Comment: This is helpful, but you still need to get the IDs. I created extension methods to help with this at https://gist.github.com/alindgren/bc670f2e0d938d1b788d38a70720e102